# Task Scheduler not running .exe when "Run whether user logged on or not"

Tags: c#, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a console app written in c# that I need to run with Task Scheduler.

If I enable "Run whether user logged on or not" the task reports as having run but does not.

All works fine if "Run only when user logged on"

Any idea what I need to change to get this to run.

I have tried running as Administrator with "Run with highest privileges" checked

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that "the task reports as having run but does not"?

Comment: Task Scheduler history reports it having run, but task did not do what it should have, Downloaded Data and Updated Sql Database

Comment: The task (and the executable) may in fact have launched and then exited prematurely (ie. before it had a chance to do what you expected it to do). Easiest way to troubleshoot this if the task history or event log doesn't reveal anything, is to break out [process monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and see what actually happens when the .exe is executed

Comment: Do you have any dependencies in the application like a mapped disk drive ie. R:? No resources are mapped when the user is logged off, which might be an error your application is not handling and just ends prematurely.

Comment: All the app does is make http request and update local sql server, I have set the task to run as administrator to elimenate all security issues

Comment: What is your database connection string like, are you using a username+pwd or just passing the current user SSPI? If the latter no user is logged in and thus no username get pushed forward in the database connection.